# RxJava2 flatMap and flatMapIterable

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

In **RxJava2**, what is the difference between `flatMap()` and `flatMapIterable()` ?

what is the logic behind `flatMapIterable()`?

Comment: is there no javadocs?

Comment: there is.but just confused.

Answer (score 7):

`flatMap`:

Maps the values of the upstream source into `Observable`s, subscribes to them and merges their result in a potentially interleaved fashion. In other words, it merges dynamically generated push sources.

`flatMapIterable`:

Maps the values of the upstream source into `Iterable`s and iterates each of them one after the other. In other words, it merges dynamically generated pull sources.

You can express `flatMapIterable` as `flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)` or `concatMap(Observable::fromIterable)`.

Apart from being a shortcut between the types, it is implemented directly and as such provides [considerably lower overhead](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/3864).